Lack of volume of recorded video from ESP32-CAM
I have this code in my esp32-cam there is no error, but when 20 seconds of video is recorded, an AVI file is created in the SD card, and it has no size, it is 0 KB and it doesn't show anything. No video or image.
The purpose of this program is to record video for 20 seconds and save it to the SD card

code:
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "FS.h"
#include "SD_MMC.h"
#include "EEPROM.h"

// Pin definitions for AI-Thinker ESP32-CAM
#define LED_PIN 33

// Camera settings
#define CAMERA_FRAME_SIZE FRAMESIZE_QVGA
#define CAMERA_QUALITY 10

// SD card settings
#define SD_CS_PIN 5

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);

  // Initialize the camera
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = 5;
  config.pin_d1 = 18;
  config.pin_d2 = 19;
  config.pin_d3 = 21;
  config.pin_d4 = 36;
  config.pin_d5 = 39;
  config.pin_d6 = 34;
  config.pin_d7 = 35;
  config.pin_xclk = 0;
  config.pin_pclk = 22;
  config.pin_vsync = 25;
  config.pin_href = 23;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = 26;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = 27;
  config.pin_pwdn = 32;
  config.pin_reset = -1;
  config.pin_xclk = 0;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  config.frame_size = CAMERA_FRAME_SIZE;
  config.jpeg_quality = CAMERA_QUALITY;
  config.fb_count = 2;

  // Camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }

  // Initialize SD card
  if (!SD_MMC.begin()) {
    Serial.println("SD Card Mount Failed");
    return;
  }
  uint64_t cardSize = SD_MMC.cardSize() / (1024 * 1024);
  Serial.printf("SD Card Size: %lluMB\n", cardSize);

  // Initialize LED pin
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long startTime = millis(); // Start time
  File videoFile = SD_MMC.open("/video.avi", FILE_WRITE);

  if (!videoFile) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for writing");
    return;
  }

  // AVI header setup
  writeAVIHeader(videoFile, 20 * 30); // Approx. 20 seconds at 30 fps

  while (millis() - startTime < 20000) { // Record for 20 seconds
    camera_fb_t *fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    if (!fb) {
      Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
      return;
    }

    // Write the frame data to the AVI file
    writeFrame(videoFile, fb);

    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);

    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    delay(1000 / 30); // Attempt to maintain 30 fps
  }

  // Finalize AVI file
  finalizeAVIFile(videoFile);
  videoFile.close();

  Serial.println("Recording complete");
  while (true); // Stop further execution
}

// Function to write the AVI header
void writeAVIHeader(File &videoFile, int frameCount) {
  // Header code goes here (omitted for brevity)
}

// Function to write a frame to the AVI file
void writeFrame(File &videoFile, camera_fb_t *fb) {
  // Frame writing code goes here (omitted for brevity)
}

// Function to finalize the AVI file (e.g., writing index)
void finalizeAVIFile(File &videoFile) {
  // Finalization code goes here (omitted for brevity)
}


I asked AI but no answers.
Help!!!!!

Make a copy of your program. Remove all the camera-related code, leaving in just the code that writes to the file. Add some code to write some text to the file ("Hello world"). Run that. Does that work? Then your problem is camera-related. Is the file empty? Then your problem is in the simpler, much smaller code you have left. If the problem is in the simpler, much smaller code you have left then edit the question and post that code instead.

There is no problem with SD card or micro or camera, I think that the problem is with the configuration of the file, I don't know how to take several photos continuously and put them one after the other to produce a video. Surely, the problem is related to the movie making algorithm. Can you help with this matter?

Not if you’re not willing to do basic debugging.
